# Get all Amazon S3 files inside a bucket within Promise

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to grab thousands of files from Amazon S3 within a Promise but I can't seem to figure out how to include the ContinuationToken within if the list is truncated and gather it all together within the promise.  I'm a novice with JS and could use some help.  Here's what I have, so far:

```
getFiles()
    .then(filterFiles)
    .then(mapUrls)
;

function getFiles(token) {
    var params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        MaxKeys: 5000,
        ContinuationToken: token
    };
    var allKeys = [];

    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) { 
        return reject(err);
      }
      allKeys.push(data.Contents)
      if (data.IsTruncated) {
        s3.listObjectsV2({Bucket: bucket, MaxKeys: 5000, ContinuationToken: data.NextContinuationToken})
        console.log('Getting more images...');
        allKeys.push(data.Contents)
      }
      resolve(data.Contents);
    });
  });

  return p;
}
```

I need the function to continue to run until I've created a list of all objects in the bucket to return.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I've got it to a point where I can gather 2000 of the files I need, but I'll need to make a few more passes.  I need some kind of recursive loop that just keeps going until `if (data.IsTruncated)` comes back false.

Comment: It looks like you need to generate additional `Promise`-s on the second and subsequent iterations, since the calls to `listObjectsV2` are asynchronous. You stop creating `Promise`-s when `data.IsTruncated` is false.

Comment: If not another `Promise`, then add code after the second `listObjectsV2` to collect the additional results (which is missing -- effectively you might be throwing the second iterations results away.)

Answer (score 1):

You need **ContinuationToken** the second time only.

```
var params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    MaxKeys: 5000,
};

if (data.IsTruncated) {
    s3.listObjectsV2({...params, ContinuationToken: data.NextContinuationToken})
```

IMO, this is just a s3 function called twice, more like a nested
call. Recursion is when a function keeps calling itself
until a specified condition is met.

Read more about recursion: https://medium.com/@vickdayaram/recursion-caad288bf621

Comment: Good point - I'll update my question with more detail.  I need the function to continue to run until all files have been retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to list all objects in the bucket using async/await and the code below to populate an array.

```
async function getFiles(objects = []) {
    const response = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
    response.Contents.forEach(obj => filelist.push(obj.Key));
    if (response.NextContinuationToken) {
        params.ContinuationToken = response.NextContinuationToken;
        await getFiles(params, objects);
    }
    console.log(filelist.length)
    return filelist;
}
```

Thanks to all who helped!